# AWS Amplifyに関する質問です

Tags: aws, aws-cli

下記のサイトを見ながら、Amplifyのチュートリアルを実施しました。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/aws-amplify-vue-3-tutorial/

```
amplify publish
```

まで問題なく実施でき、出てきたURLにアクセスし、表示されるのも確認しました。

その後、ブラウザでAWSを開いて、AmplifyやDynamoDBのページを開いても、何も作成されていません。自分のイメージだと、ユーザー情報の登録やtodoリストの登録にDynamoDBを使っているはずだから、DynamoDBのページに何かしら自動的に作られているのかなと思っていました。また、amplify publishしているのだから、Amplifyのページにも何かしら作られていると思っていましたが、作られていませんでした。

```
amplify publish
```

を実行すると、どこに何が作られているのでしょうか。